# Python pip install appkit

Tags: python, pip

I'm using python 3.6 and wanted to install appkit
I paste last logs. I tryed everything.
I got installed Visual Studio 2015.
I'm using Windows 7

```
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\cairo
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe
/c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_
MINOR=17 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=0 -Ic:\python36\include -Ic:\python36\include "
-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program
Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files
(x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windo
ws Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\inc
lude\10.0.10586.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0
.10586.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10586.0\winr
t" /Tccairo/device.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\cairo/device.obj
    device.c
    c:\users\rafal\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-l744mfh7\pycairo\cairo\pycairo
.h(37): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cairo.h': No such file or
directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\B
IN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\
\Users\\rafal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l744mfh7\\pycairo\\setup.py';f=
getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.
close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\rafal\A
ppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-r_uz_0uc\install-record.txt --single-version-extern
ally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\rafal\AppData\Local
\Temp\pip-install-l744mfh7\pycairo\
```

**pip install pygobject**

```
Collecting pygobject
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/e8/1e4f21800015a9ca153
969e85fc29f7962f8f82fc5dbc1ecbdeb9dc54c75/PyGObject-3.28.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pycairo>=1.11.1 in c:\python36\lib\site-packages
(from pygobject) (1.16.3)
Installing collected packages: pygobject
  Running setup.py install for pygobject ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\rafal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ijzat7z
3\\pygobject\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read(
).replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
 --record C:\Users\rafal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ded1xvyr\install-record.t
xt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat\generictreemodel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygtkcomp
at
    copying pygtkcompat\pygtkcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygtkcompat
    copying pygtkcompat\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pygtkcompat
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    copying gi\docstring.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    copying gi\importer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    copying gi\module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    copying gi\pygtkcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    copying gi\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    copying gi\_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    copying gi\_error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    copying gi\_option.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    copying gi\_ossighelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    copying gi\_propertyhelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    copying gi\_signalhelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    copying gi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi\repository
    copying gi\repository\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi\repository
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\Gdk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\GIMarshallingTests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi\ove
rrides
    copying gi\overrides\Gio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\GLib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\GObject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\Gtk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\keysyms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\Pango.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi\overrides
    copying gi\overrides\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\gi\overrides
    running build_ext
    pycairo: new API
    pycairo: trying include directory: 'c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\cairo'

    pycairo: header file ('c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\cairo\\py3cairo.h')
 not found
    pycairo: old API
    pycairo: found pycairo 1.16.3 (c:\python36\lib\site-packages)
    pycairo: trying include directory: 'c:\\python36\\include\\pycairo'
    pycairo: header file ('c:\\python36\\include\\pycairo\\py3cairo.h') not foun
d
    pycairo: pkg-config
    error: Could not find pycairo headers

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\
\Users\\rafal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ijzat7z3\\pygobject\\setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\rafal
\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ded1xvyr\install-record.txt --single-version-exte
rnally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\rafal\AppData\Loc
al\Temp\pip-install-ijzat7z3\pygobject\



C:\Users\rafal\Downloads>pip install pycairo
Requirement already satisfied: pycairo in c:\python36\lib\site-packages (1.16.3)
```

I downloaded GTK , by using this tutorial
https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php
And PygoObject by using this tutorial:
http://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

`appkit` on Windows uses `PyGObject` which requires `PyCairo` which requires `cairo` which you don't have. You have to install [cairo](https://cairographics.org/download/) with sources.

Comment: I installed PyCairo from 
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo
I still have to install cairo? Because when i'm using pip install cairo i got erros.
Is it neccessery to install Cairo either?

Comment: You cannot `pip install cairo` because cairo is not a Python module — PyCairo is. Even if you've installed PyCairo you still need cairo *sources* because PyGObject needs them for compilation. Unfortunately there is no PyGObject for Python 3.6 at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, only for Python 2.7.

Comment: Ok thanks for info. I installed python 2.7 and rest things fromhttps://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
(Pycairo and Pygobject) then i used pip install appkit.
I had to download from this website because when i used pip i had error with C++ Visual