# installing pyGObject has an error in pycharm

Tags: python, windows, pip, pycharm, pygobject

while i'm trying to install pyGObject in my Pycharm. it does not work. and has an error :

error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2]

[image]
and the output command :

```
 running build_ext
    building 'cairo._cairo' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\cairo
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MINOR=18 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=0 -IC:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\Testt\venv\include -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /Tccairo/device.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\cairo/device.obj
    device.c
    c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\pycairo\cairo\pycairo.h(37) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cairo.h': No such file or directory
    error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
```

my python version is 3.4.8 and working in windows 8.1

Comment: If you're using python 3.4 in Windows, I'd recommend using this installer https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pip install appkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845946/python-pip-install-appkit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Cannot+open+include+file%3A+cairo.h